# Trying to convert into datetime from varchar(50), todays date + have only hours minutes and seconds

Tags: sql, datetime, time

I have a temp table that I am trying to convert the date which is shown below to datetime. The column is set to varchar(50). The data was transferred from a csv file that had a 50 character length.

```
[CODE]
SELECT [Date]
  ,Patient
  ,ISNULL(Doctor,-1) AS Doctor
  ,[Procedure]
  ,CAST(Charge AS decimal(8,2)) AS ChargeDecimal 
FROM ##TempBellevueLoadCSV

--Result:
Date
00:00.0
15:00.0 --Shown below:
00:00.0
00:00.0

--Need Datetime format with today's date added like below: 
Date
2017-03-08 15:00:00.000
```

---

```
 SELECT 

     CAST('0000-00-00 '+ SUBSTRING(CAST(t.[Date] AS varchar(8)),1, 7)+'0.000'
               AS varchar) AS [Date]
     ,Patient 
     ,Doctor 
     ,[Procedure] 
     ,CAST(Charge AS decimal(8,2)) AS Charge 
 FROM ##TempBellevueLoadCSV as t

 --This looks like it, but cannot cast into datetime.

 --Could I do this??? Doesn't work.
 CAST(GETDATE()+[Date]) AS datetime
```

### [/CODE]

--Update: I need the current date added with the hours minutes seconds as part of the data. How do I add today's date add to the hours, minutes, seconds that I already have?

Comment: What database are you using? This affects what date functions are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with using SSIS in adding a derived column, replacing time and 
     adding a line of code: 
     [Code]
     (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GETDATE()) + RIGHT("0" + 
     (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GETDATE()),2) + RIGHT("0" + 
     [image]
     (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GETDATE()),2) + Time
     [/Code]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,[Date],103)[Date]
,Patient
,ISNULL(Doctor,-1) AS Doctor
,[Procedure]
,CAST(Charge AS decimal(8,2)) AS ChargeDecimal 
FROM ##TempBellevueLoadCSV
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but this did not work. I need the date added to the hours minutes and seconds that I have already. I really appreciate you helping!

Comment: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.